# Checking download verification of program in terminal

Tags: python, command-line, terminal

I have been given instructions to verify a program (Twilio) was actually downloaded. But it is not working. The error message leads me to believe I am not using the correct code. Please advise how to properly verify if a program has been downloaded in the terminal.

**Install Verification Code:**

```
import twilio
print(twilio.__version__)
```

**Terminal:**

```
import twilio
-bash: import: command not found
print(twilio.__version__)
-bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'twilio.__version__'
```

Comment: You have to start the python interpreter with the command `python`

Comment: Ah quick fix! Great thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As Patrick suggests, you have to start the python interpreter with the command `python`

Verify [install](https://www.twilio.com/docs/libraries/python):

```
>>>import twilio
```